# the `existing` arg of `merge` is getting old cached results on a new query with different `keyArgs`

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

My understanding of the [Apollo pagination docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api) is that if you've specified `keyArgs` in your field policy, then any queries that specify different args should result in separately cached results.

So, given a query that looks something like this:

```
items(input:{state, limit, cursor}) {
  cursor
  items: { ... ItemBase }
  totalCount
}
```

And a field policy that looks like this (using their [example cursor pagination code](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/#keeping-cursors-separate-from-items)):

```
items: {
    keyArgs: ['state'],
    merge(existing, incoming, { readField }) {
      const items = existing ? { ...existing.items } : {};
      incoming.items.forEach((item) => {
        items[readField('id', item) as string] = item;
      });

      return {
        cursor: incoming.cursor,
        items,
        totalCount: incoming.totalCount,
      };
    },
    read(existing) {
      if (existing) {
        return {
          cursor: existing.cursor,
          items: Object.values(existing.items),
          totalCount: items.totalCount,
        };
      }
      return undefined;
    },
  },
```

I would imagine that doing a query with different states would result in separately cached values, where an initial lazy `getItems` would mean that the `existing` in `merge` is undefined.

Instead, if I do something like `getItems(expired)` -> `fetchMore(expired)` -> `getItems(active)`, then on the last network request for active I end up seeing the cached results for expired items passed in to the `existing` arg in merge. What am I doing wrong here?